# html drop-down button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the drop-down button. It is not working in my chrome.
Here is my html code-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>IconMaker</title>
<meta charset=utf-8">
<meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize the page to understand Responsiveness</p> 
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Post Ideas
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Work 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  <p>If you want to use Paypal</p>
  <i class="fa fa-cc-paypal" style="font-size:36px"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  <p>If you want to use Mastercard</p>
  <i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard" style="font-size:36px"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  <p>If you want to use Visa</p>
  <i class="fa fa-cc-visa" style="font-size:36px"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  <p>If you want to use Google Wallet</p>
  <i class="fa fa-google-wallet" style="font-size:36px"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  <p>If you want to use American Express</p>
  <i class="fa fa-cc-amex" style="font-size:36px"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I click on drop-down, nothing drops down. I see no errors on my console.I have added bootstrap.js in html. Does i have to use JavaScript file for that?

Comment: why have you included CSS of bootstrap in version 4.0.0-beta and JS version of 3.3.7? Include it in same version and test once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Cuz you use version 4.0.0-beta in css and another version in javascript

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the below css

```
.show > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the cause of the problem.
Problem cause different versions

Comment: If you read the documentation for the bootstrap 4.0 you can see the css is

    ```.show>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }```
can you please recheck from your end